# How to run XUnit test using data from a CSV file

Tags: c#, selenium, csv, xunit

Is there a way to run a data driven `XUnit` test using a `CSV` file as the data source? I've tried `Cavity.Data.XUnit`, but it's no longer compatible with the newest version of `XUnit`. So far, I've only been able to achieve this using Excel files, but I need to change them to `CSV` instead.

An example:

```
[Theory]
[ExcelData(@"Settings\TestFileParam.xls", "Select url, username, password, from TestData")]
//^Replace with a CSV file instead
public void Tester_Method(string url, string username, string password)
{
    //Code reading the data from CSV
    Assert.True(something);
}
```

Comment: I am just curious. What you trying to test and what are these data from file?

Comment: - `What you trying to test`: I'm running UI Test for a website. I'm using Selenium in a separate solution which I'm using as the framework. 
- `what are these data from file` the data is coming from an excel file in 2003-07 format

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to create a custom xUnit.Sdk.DataAttribute. This is an example which will read in data in this form.

MyCsv.csv

```
sep=,
csvRowOne,csvRowTwo,csvRowThree
15,"Just A Test","Apples are Red"
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
  [Theory]
  [CsvData(@"C:\MyCsv.csv")]
  public void TestWithCSVData(int csvRowOne, string csvRowTwo, string csvRowThree)
```

It just parses strings and ints, but you can extend the ConvertParameter method to do more.

CsvDataAttribute.cs

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class CsvDataAttribute : DataAttribute
{
    private readonly string _fileName;
    public CsvDataAttribute(string fileName)
    {
        _fileName = fileName;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        var pars = testMethod.GetParameters();
        var parameterTypes = pars.Select(par => par.ParameterType).ToArray();
        using (var csvFile = new StreamReader(_fileName))
        {
            csvFile.ReadLine();// Delimiter Row: "sep=,". Comment out if not used
            csvFile.ReadLine(); // Headings Row. Comment out if not used
            string line;
            while ((line = csvFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var row = line.Split(',');
                yield return ConvertParameters((object[])row, parameterTypes);
            }
        }
    }

    private static object[] ConvertParameters(IReadOnlyList<object> values, IReadOnlyList<Type> parameterTypes)
    {
        var result = new object[parameterTypes.Count];
        for (var idx = 0; idx < parameterTypes.Count; idx++)
        {
            result[idx] = ConvertParameter(values[idx], parameterTypes[idx]);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static object ConvertParameter(object parameter, Type parameterType)
    {
        return parameterType == typeof(int) ? Convert.ToInt32(parameter) : parameter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

xUnit does not have this exact capability built in, it does however have extension points for type of use case. Much of xUnit can be replaced and customized, new test case data sources are one of the more common ones.

The `Xunit.Sdk.DataAttribute` is the extension point the `ExcelDataAttribute` uses.

A typical implementation would look something like this

```
public class CsvDataAttribute : DataAttribute
{
    readonly string fileName;

    public CsvDataAttribute(string fileName)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo testMethod)
    {
        //Parse CSV and return an object[] for each test case
    }
}
```

The implementation of `ExcelDataAttribute` is found here. https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/885edfc2e84ec4934cd137a985c3b06dda043ab5/ExcelDataExample/ExcelDataAttribute.cs

Comment: `ExcelDataAttribute` implementation doesn't exist anymore in github repository.  The link provided no longer exist.