# xUnit test using data coming from external file

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

In these days I'm trying to understand how xUnit tests work and, in particular, I discovered that there are 3 ways to pass data as parameters in order to test class methods (InlineData, ClassData and MemberData). But here Is my issue: is there any chance to get these data from an external file? (For example a Json file)
I wasn't unable to find enough material about this topic, thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the cleanest way is using `ClassData` for that so that you can populate data for your test from wherever you like. Consider this:

```
public class TestData : IEnumerable<object[]> 
{
    private IEnumerable<object[]> ReadFile() 
    {
        //read your file
    }

    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator() 
    {
        var items = ReadFile();
        return items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Of course, you could just populate data from a file during [the Arrange phase of your test](https://medium.com/@pjbgf/title-testing-code-ocd-and-the-aaa-pattern-df453975ab80) and then just loop your test method over the data. But in that case, you would lose the advantage of detecting all failing tests instead of just the first.

Answer (score 29):

xUnit has been designed to be extensible, i.a. via the [DataAttribute](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core/Sdk/DataAttribute.cs).

[InlineData](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core/InlineDataAttribute.cs), [ClassData](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core/ClassDataAttribute.cs) and [MemberData](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core/MemberDataAttribute.cs) all derive from `DataAttribute`, which you can extend yourself to create a custom data source for a data theory, in which you may read from you external file and use e.g. [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize your data.

User [Sock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6375486/sock) wrote about this in his blog regarding *JSON*, as you mentioned:

- [Creating a custom xUnit theory test DataAttribute to load data from JSON files](https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-custom-xunit-theory-test-dataattribute-to-load-data-from-json-files/)
- [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/andrewlock/blog-examples/tree/master/XUnitTheoryTests/XUnitTheoryTests)

Related question with data from *CSV* file:
[How to run XUnit test using data from a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727394/how-to-run-xunit-test-using-data-from-a-csv-file)

And here are two *xUnit* samples:

- [ExcelData](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/0c8ef4e4291b0ddc98469ad1317d3ad0c7904ce7/ExcelDataExample)
- [SqlData](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/tree/0c8ef4e4291b0ddc98469ad1317d3ad0c7904ce7/SqlDataExample)

Comment: thx, this article really helped https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-custom-xunit-theory-test-dataattribute-to-load-data-from-json-files/  However, I have to rebuild my tests project every time I modify the JSON file. Simply building won't update the file, even if Copy Always is set on the file